# How to print a canvas from android device using FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, pascal

how does one print a canvas from a Android device using delphi FMX. I am able to print on windows, But print Dialog isnt compatible with android, How could I print from the android device to my printer ?

Answer (score 1):

use winsoft printing library at https://www.winsoft.sk/aprinting.htm and then add to library path in settings, add Winsoft.Android.Print to uses, and then use the printing function like so (I had a canvas and had to convert it to a bitmap to print)

```
procedure TfrmFinal.printBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
screenshot: TBitmap; // WINSOFT CAN PRINT BITMAPS, HTML, PDFS AND MORE.
 begin
    screenshot := showItemsSlip.MakeScreenshot;

   if SystemSupportsPrint then 
    PrintBitmap(screenshot,'logo',TColorMode.Monochrome,TOrientation.Portrait, TScaleMode.Fit)
else
ShowMessage('Printing is not supported on this device'); 
end;
```